# Magento 2 : how to get category name in product grid

Tags: magento2

I want to create 1 more column to display all categories of that product, I have tried many ways on google but none of them work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are (certainly) not the first one to want this. Check these one out:

- https://github.com/aune-io/magento2-product-grid-category-filter
- https://github.com/MeetanshiInc/Add-Category-Column-to-Product-Grid-in-Magento-2
- https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-category-filter
- https://github.com/aune-io/magento2-product-grid-category-filter/blob/master/README.md

You can try one of these out, or use it as inspiration for your own module.